# Using RJSONIO and AsIs class

Tags: json, r, text

I am writing some helper functions to convert my R variables to JSON.  I've come across this problem: I would like my values to be represented as JSON arrays, this can be done using the AsIs class according to the RJSONIO documentation.

```
x = "HELLO"
toJSON(list(x = I(x)), collapse="")

"{ \"x\": [ \"HELLO\" ] }"
```

But say we have a list

```
y = list(a = "HELLO", b = "WORLD")
toJSON(list(y = I(y)), collapse="")

"{ \"y\": {\n \"a\": \"HELLO\",\n\"b\": \"WORLD\" \n} }"
```

The value found in y -> a is NOT represented as an array.  Ideally I would have

```
"{ \"y\": [{\n \"a\": \"HELLO\",\n\"b\": \"WORLD\" \n}] }"
```

Note the square brackets.  Also I would like to get rid of all "\n"s, but collapse does not eliminate the line breaks in nested JSON.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try writing as

```
y = list(list(a = "HELLO", b = "WORLD"))
test<-toJSON(list(y = I(y)), collapse="")
```

when you write to file it appears as:

```
{ "y": [
 {
 "a": "HELLO",
"b": "WORLD" 
} 
] }
```

I guess you could remove the \n as

```
test<-gsub("\n","",test)
```

or use RJSON package

```
> rjson::toJSON(list(y = I(y)))
[1] "{\"y\":[{\"a\":\"HELLO\",\"b\":\"WORLD\"}]}"
```

The reason

```
> names(list(a = "HELLO", b = "WORLD"))
[1] "a" "b"
> names(list(list(a = "HELLO", b = "WORLD")))
NULL
```

examining the rjson::toJSON you will find this snippet of code

```
  if (!is.null(names(x))) 
            return(toJSON(as.list(x)))
        str = "["
```

so it would appear to need an unnamed list to treat it as a JSON array. Maybe RJSONIO is similar.